# using python to extract data with duplicate names from a json array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'll start by apologising if I use the wrong terms here, I am a rank beginner with python.
I have a json array containing 5 sets of data. The corresponding items in each set have duplicate names. I can extract them in java but not in python. The item(s) I want are called "summary_polyline". I have tried so many different ways in the last couple of weeks, so far nothing works.
This is the relevant part of my python-

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

import polyline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

with open ('/var/www/vk7krj/running/strava_activities.json', 'rt') as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()

#print (contents)
#print (contents["summary_polyline"[1]])
activity1 = contents("summary_polyline"[1])
```

If I un-comment "print content", it prints the file to the screen ok.
I ran the json through an on-line json format checker and it passed ok
How do I extract the five "summay_polylines" and assign them to "activity1" to "activity5"?

Comment: Thanks for doing the edit James, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understand you, you need convert to json text data which was red from file.

```
with open ('/var/www/vk7krj/running/strava_activities.json', 'rt') as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()
    
# json_contents is a List with dicts now
json_contents = json.loads(contents)
# list with activities
activities = []
for dict_item in json_contents:
    activities.append(dict_item)
# print all activities (whole file)
print(activities)
# print first activity
print(activities[0])
# print second activity
print(activities[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, the file is 11k- is it ok to put it up here?

Comment: Just re-read you answer Andrei, I don't want to put data in to a json, I need to extract it  from a json array.

Comment: Ok, let's find out the details)) Do you have a format file like this: {'t': ['a', 'b', 'c']}?

Comment: Almost- it starts like this-  [{"resource_state": 2, "athlete": {"id": 35005370, "resource_state": 1}, "name": "Bellerive parkrun", "distance": 5035.0, "moving_time": 1973,

Comment: Andrei, I've just put a link to the file at https://vk7krj.com/Ffiles.html  Second item down is a hyperlink to the file. A right click & download should do the trick.

Comment: I could'n save it(( wrong url. If I right understand, in the json list you have repetitive items like a dict. So I corrected my above answer.

Comment: For reasons I don't yet understand you have to right click & save as- a left click doesn't work- but then I am very much a beginner at this. In my python, I just did a print (type() and it says class 'list'. And yes, it is a repetitive list.

Comment: I have corrected answer with code, please try this solution

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but it doesn't work- print(activities) prints the whole file, print(activity1) and print(activity2) don't print anything.

Comment: Sorry, Ken I made error)) just one minute)

Comment: Sorry for the delay Andei, had to attend to family business. The code woks, thanks, but I still need to extract just the 5 "summay_polylines" . They are the lat/long coordinates of the activity, which is what I am after. Do you have any advice for me to help me do that?

Comment: Ok, Ken. This is my email: a_ndron.89@mail.ru - send me your json file